# Is it possible to record audio to variable/RAM in LiveCode?

Tags: livecode

Is it possible to record audio to a variable/RAM in LiveCode?
Normal recording requires to use a file, but I'm trying to figure out a way to not have to use the extra step of writing to disk, only to then read it from disk and send through sockets.

Comment: If you want to send it through sockets, then you aren't really recording it to a variable or RAM. Instead, you are streaming it.

Comment: Yes I'm quite aware of that, but the first step is to put it *somewhere* before you can send it over Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently impossible and there is no good way to stream content from within LiveCode. When I tried to use video recording and sockets at the same time, I ran into a bug that caused LiveCode (Revolution at the time) to crash. Looking into the crash files, it appeared to me that using the recording routines and the socket routines at the same time caused a memory address conflict. After sending roughly 1000 recorded frames through a socket, Revolution would inevitably crash. To my best knowledge, this problem has never been fixed.

I would recommend dedicated software for streaming. A possibility might be VLC. You can use VLC from the command line, which means that you can set up a stream from within LiveCode, using the `shell()` function.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.
I was hoping there was some way to implement this in LiveCode, and not have to use other solutions, but I guess not.